# What is the difference between Yang-Mills theory and ${\cal N}=4$ supersymmetric Yang-Mills theory (SYM)

Tags: field-theory, feynman-diagrams, supersymmetry, yang-mills

I am a beginner trying to learn Quantum Field theories.
I understand the basics of Quantum Electrodynamics and the emergence of Feynman diagrams from the perturbative expansion of the generating functional. I would like to understand [Yang-Mills theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory).
Could anyone please clarify

1. What´s the difference between Yang-Mills theory and ${\cal N}=4$ SYM? Are both theories strongly coupled theories?
2. Can we have a perturbative expansion of generating functional and Feynman diagrams for Yang-Mills theories?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [QCD Feynman rules](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2020f/qcdfr.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1)What´s the difference between Yang-Mills theory and N=4  SYM?

Super-Yang-Mills theory is a supersymmetric extension of Yang-Mills theory, meaning that in addition to the gauge field and perhaps fermions and/or scalars coupled to it, that one might find in Yang-Mills, one also has superpartners of these fields - e.g. in addition to the gluons, one has gluinos in N=1, gluinos and sgluons in N=2, etc. [The N=4 supermultiplet was described in this answer.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341932/matter-content-of-mathcaln-4-sym)

Stephen Martin's regularly updated [Supersymmetry Primer](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709356) is a down-to-earth introduction to supersymmetry.

> Are both theories strongly coupled theories?

The coupling is a free parameter. It can be small or large or anything in between. Remember that the electroweak theory is a Yang-Mills theory too!

> 2)Can we have a perturbative expansion of generating functional and
> Feynman diagrams for Yang-Mills theories? Thanks in advance

Yes, this is even described [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory#Quantization). Though for strong coupling you need other methods, like lattice calculations.